# asp.net listview grouptemplate is not working

Tags: asp.net, listview

I am using a listview control to show a list of items in a tabular form; repeating horizontally in groups of 6 items. However this is not working at all for me. I always get one item per row regardless of the "GroupItemCount" setting. Am I missing something in the code below. Any help or comments are highly appreciated!

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="SystemsListView" DataSourceID="PharmacySystemsEDS" GroupItemCount="6">
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
<GroupTemplate>
    <tr>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </tr>
</GroupTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <td>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input runat="server" id="SystemCheckBox" type="checkbox" value='<%#Eval("SystemId")%>'>
            <%#Eval("SystemName")%>
        </label>
    </td>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: `ListView` list Items horizontally using its `GroupItemCount` property.What you are trying to Achieve? You will get 6 Items Per row

Answer (score 0):

You're definening `GroupItemCount` properly. What you're missing is the placeholder declarations. When you define `ListView` properties, make sure you populate `ItemPlaceholderID` and `GroupPlaceholderID` properties as well. Here is the modified version of your code snippet:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" 
    ID="SystemsListView" 
    DataSourceID="PharmacySystemsEDS" 
    GroupItemCount="6" 
    ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder" 
    GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceholder">
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
<GroupTemplate>
    <tr>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </tr>
</GroupTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <td>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input runat="server" id="SystemCheckBox" type="checkbox" value='<%#Eval("SystemId")%>'>
            <%#Eval("SystemName")%>
        </label>
    </td>
</ItemTemplate>
```